# Excel VBA AutoFilter Error Filtering with Date Range

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, autofilter

My goal is to filter a range of rows by a date in column A.  I am using parameter Criteria1 to specify the first operator & date, Criteria2 for the second operator and date, and "xlAnd" for the Operator parameter.

The range of dates to filter are in rows 2 to 1255 of column A...

```
Range("A2:A1255").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">10/1/2022", Operator:="xlAnd", Criteria2:="<12/1/2022"
```

However, the following error is raised when this code is attempted:

```
Error 1004:  AutoFilter method of Range class failed
```

As a workaround, I tried two consecutive AutoFilters, for each criteria.  Unfortunately, the second filter did not filter on the output from the first filter, but also on the range as a whole.

I am at a loss.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `Operator:="xlAnd"` should be `Operator:=xlAnd`

Comment: Also `">" & DateSerial(2022, 1, 10)` is recomended instead of `">10/1/2022"` . Similarly for `"<12/1/2022"`. Make that `"<" & DateSerial(2022, 1,12)`. Here I am assuming that `1` is `January`.

Comment: Also, you want to include the headers when auto filtering i.e. `"A1:A1255"`. If you're not using the hardcoded values as the criteria, show us how you're doing it. Maybe you're doing something wrong in the conversions.

Comment: Siddharth:  Changing the value of the Operator parameter to a hard-coded xlAnd fixed the problem.  I was passing in this value to the function running filter, and assigning it to the parameter.  Changing it the hard-coded value brought success.  And, although keeping my dates formatted as "m/d/yyyy" worked, I'll change the filtering to use the more acceptable DateSerial formatting you suggest.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you also passing the operator `xlAnd` to the function as variable?

Comment: Additionally, passing in the numeric equivalent of xlAnd (1)  would have fixed the problem as well,

Comment: correct. If you want you can share your function and code and i can then give you exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to specify the date as below and `xlAnd` is a const without quotation.

```vb
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$1255").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">2022/10/1", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<2022/12/1"
```

Comment: taller:  I attempted your suggestion, changing the format of the two criteria dates to "yyyy/m/d", with no change in results.

Comment: @papablue62 Have you changed `Operator:=xlAnd`? It is the root cause of run-time error.